# Is there a chance that a [status-declined] question may turn into a [status-completed] one?

Tags: support, tags

I've seen a few ideas here that were unfortunately marked as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Does this mean that such an idea is a lost cause and arguing over it is pointless, or is it possible that the SE team may change it's views and make it a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), *et cetera*?

If any, are there any examples of questions changing from [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Comment: this seems to have happened [122 times](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/712403) on MSE

Comment: Hmm, there were 1,768 [meta-tag:status-declined] questions and 122 got changed, then there's a 6.9% chance that a [meta-tag:status-declined] won't stay that way. Hmm, sounds reassuring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some features are just blatantly never going to happen, like the various requests to have monetary rewards integrated into the site. People can keep requesting it, but that decline is *never* gonna change.

On the other hand, there are plenty of cases where a decline simply means "not right now." It's perfectly possible that it will be reconsidered at a later time, and there are cases where a previously declined feature has later been implemented. One example is the [ability to retract close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes).

Features can be re-evaluated for a variety of reasons after initially being declined, such as:

- What wasn't a problem before is now becoming a consistent problem.
- Someone brings to light other factors not previously considered.
- Changes in the system make it much easier to implement another feature.

Comment: In this case, would the SE team always mention whether if it's declined for good or there's a possibility of change?

Comment: If we know it's something we'll reconsider later, then sure. But that can sometimes be hard to predict.

Comment: "*On the other hand, there are plenty of cases where a decline simply means 'not right now.' *" In such a situation, wouldn't status-planned or status-deferred make more sense, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Unitato status-planned or status-deferred, especially status-planned, carry the expectation that it will be done eventually. This is not always the case. Probably a better description would that  there are plenty of cases where a decline simply means 'not right now', *but possibly never*. As animuson says in the comment, it can be hard to predict if something will be reconsiderd, and status-deferred basically says they will.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks @wythagoras