# When you hover over the name of the person closing a question it should show the reason they've chosen

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, attribution

I originally posted this on UserVoice, but I'm moving it here.

It is somewhat annoying when you close a question, but are not the last person closing it, that the official close reason doesn't necessarily match the reason you've chosen.  I'd like to be able to see the reason that each voter has chosen in addition to the official close reason.

If the reason was kept along with the close vote (a FK to the reasons table wouldn't take much space), then it could be provided as a hover over on the person's name when the close message is shown.

Comment: See this question: [Show all voted close types when a question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/show-all-voted-close-types-when-a-question-is-closed)

Comment: Yes it's a dupe (with a different suggestion to solve it) the original was declined.

Answer (score 13):

I like it that you suggest a hover, it wouldn't take up space in the UI, kinda like the net votes thingy on posts

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps there should be an official reason, and  a separator, footnote<sup>+</sup> indicator, or other distinguishing mark to indicate that you can hover over other names.

> **closed** as off topic by [Moderator User♦](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/857/kevin-vermeer), [Agrees with mod](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users), [Other user 1<sup>*</sup>](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users), and [Other user 2<sup>*</sup>](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users)

or

> **closed** as off topic by [Moderator User♦](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/857/kevin-vermeer), and by [Other user 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users), [Other user 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users), and [Other user 3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users)

(Hover for close reasons implemented im markdown).

---

<sup>+</sup> Like this.