# Evaluate the FR for: Add increase/decrease indent buttons to the wysiwyg editor

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, editor

A long time ago there was a feature request asking [to add increase/decrease indent buttons to the editor toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8144/243527):

> These should work by adding spaces or removing spaces from the beginning of the current line or every line between the start and end of a text selection (inclusive).

What was being asked for is something like this in the post editor:

[image: indent/outdent buttons]

So that poorly indented code like this can be formatted easier without being forced to use copy/paste and an external editor or hammering the space bar:

```
while(true) {
if (this) {
if (that) {
stuff();
}
}
}
```

The linked question doesn't have a feature-request status tag and does have an accepted answer which apparently [is a bit of a problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258365/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-when-a-post-is-tagged-with-feature-request/258377#comment36135_258377). So, in accordance with advice in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2532/243527) here on meta:

**Please add +/- indent buttons to the standard editor toolbar**

---

### Why ask this question *again*?

Seems some clarification on my motives are necessary so:

> *[Does an accepted answer influence/affect a feature request at all?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258365/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-when-a-post-is-tagged-with-feature-request/258377#comment36135_258377)*
>
> It can cause some confusion as to whether the request has been handled or not ... We actively encourage users not to accept answers on feature requests that haven't been acknowledged for this very reason. - animuson♦

The linked request *has* an accepted answer but is neither implemented, declined nor acknowledged. I don't know whether it's even *on* the team's radar as there is no open question related to it (there *are* many closed duplicates) - Yet I feel would be quite beneficial. I'd be more than satisfied with an official "[we know about that request and concluded status-meh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233638/evaluate-the-fr-for-add-increase-decrease-indent-buttons-to-the-wysiwyg-editor#comment766976_233638)" but there *is no* response and being a question with an accepted answer implies incorrectly it doesn't need one.

> [Better bump is editing existing requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233638/add-increase-decrease-indent-buttons-to-the-wysiwyg-editor#comment766965_233638) - Shadow Wizard

That doesn't un-accept an answer - I don't know if that has any impact on ["The Stack Exchange devs have a tool that lists feature-request-tagged posts across the network"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258365/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-when-a-post-is-tagged-with-feature-request/258377#comment35975_258365) - does it?

> or adding bounty - Shadow Wizard

I can do that - does it achieve anything though? Again, I can find no references as to whether that affects the SE dev's tool or not.

> not posting deliberate duplicates - Shadow Wizard

If the answer I've referenced is *not* the right way to bump an existing feature request - is there a reference for what *is* the right way to do it? I remain somewhat confused as to whether I've found and followed the wrong advice.

Comment: @ShadowWizard May I ask why you've flagged this as a duplicate of the question I'm trying to bump?

Comment: Because time is not a factor. If something was already asked, asking it again is a duplicate no matter how you will try to paint it. I'm not saying delete this one, dupes are fine, but proper action is closing it. Better bump is editing existing requests, adding answers or adding bounty, not posting deliberate duplicates.

Comment: Is the answer to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/how-to-handle-a-resubmission-of-a-feature-request) inaccurate, or is [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258365/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-when-a-post-is-tagged-with-feature-request/258377#comment36135_258377) inaccurate? If this is closed as a duplicate the feature-request will again, surely, become invisible or at least reach no visible conclusion.

Comment: @AD7six: Because this is not the way to bump an existing feature request. You could put a bounty on that old post instead.

Comment: There are thousands of feature requests, the team can't possibly answer to all of them. They pick some sometimes, we can't have control over this. Bumping with edit or bounty gives it a chance, other than that really nothing we can do, and surely asking same thing again as new question every X days/weeks/months won't help. (dupes are useful for easier search, adding more possible keywords)

Comment: @AD7six: And feature requests are just that: *requests*. If developer resources come available and it is thought to be a priority, it'll be implemented. Otherwise, not so much. You can vote on such posts, and bounties also help make it more visibible. Votes on feature requests are one factor that *can* make a feature request increase in priority.

Comment: It has a status: `status-meh`. The devs don't care enough about it to plan for it, nor do choose to decline it. It is on the 'nice-to-have' pile, the 'when-we-get-to-it'. There is no more specific status for that.

Comment: Ironic dupe closure is ironic.