# "Closed by" is incorrect

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Do not give the impression that all votes are unanimously in favor of the winning close-reason. I closed for "belongs on superuser," yet SO claims I closed for a completely different reason.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319199

Comment: That's democracy---the people have elected the president, even those that didn't :)

Comment: Explicitly stating "Jonathan voted x" is not democracy :)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/show-all-voted-close-types-when-a-question-is-closed

Comment: This is *not* a dupe. See my edit above.

Comment: Close enough. Starting to get into the realm of "my feature request asked it to be *blue* not *green*"

Comment: I still don't understand... the previous request was to have voter names grouped by close reason. Are you requesting that your name not be displayed at all?

Comment: @Shog9, Sure. Show only those who voted for the majority vote, or show no names at all. But don't say I voted for something that I didn't.

Comment: You did though. You voted to close the post, and the post got closed. Sure, you didn't give the same reason for your vote as everyone else did, but *you still voted*... right?

Comment: I voted, but "Voted as not-programming-related by Jonathan Sampson" is incorrect. How would you like it if they did the same thing with elections in your state/country? Just tag your name onto whoever wins.

Comment: As long as you don't focus on the solution in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/show-all-voted-close-types-when-a-question-is-closed (and since you obviously care about this issue) I've reopened. But I still think that the solution in #926 is better all around.

Comment: Thank you, Kyle. I've edited my request to clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Would like to see it show up only those names in the majority, quietly leaving out the names that chose other reasons.

Current:

> Closed as "not ninja turtle related" by Splinter, Bebop, April O'neil, Casey Jones, Usagi Yojimbo an hour ago

Less clutter, less disinformation:

> Closed as "not ninja turtle related" by Splinter, Casey Jones, Usagi Yojimbo an hour ago

You'd still show the majority vote, you'd still show those who voted for that particular reason, but you don't mislead people by saying they all threw down for the same slice of pizza.

If you wanted transparency for all close votes, but didn't want to clutter it up more with other reasons, why not just list the names as other closers, but not linked to that particular choice?

> Closed as "not ninja turtle related" by Splinter, Casey Jones, Usagi Yojimbo (other reasons by Shredder, Krang) an hour ago

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's a perfectly reasonable suggestion.

Comment: No, simply because if you vote to close it should be known. All the votes do the same thing, the only difference is the message attached. If by voting against the majority you can still close the post without your name being attached, then you can avoid responsibility for your actions and hide in the shadows. I'm a big fan of transparency.

Comment: @Ian, I'm looking forward to what you can suggest then. How might you change the "closed by" message so that it doesn't imply a unanimous support for a particular option?

Comment: Don't really care for this suggestion... I'd rather see us abolish voter names on closed questions entirely rather than let *some* voters squeak by anonymously simply because they chose a different close reason. That would only make sense if it took 5 votes *with the same reason* to close a question.

Comment: Need another downvote for 2199, make it happen people!

Comment: @Shog9, perhaps you're on to something. Maybe SO should require 5 votes for a particular reason before it's closed.

Comment: @Jonathan: in most cases, i don't think it matters - frankly, i don't care if an off-topic question is closed because it's not programming related, because it belongs on server fault, or because it belongs on super user: the key point is, it *doesn't* belong on SO, therefore it should be closed.

Comment: @Shog9, I agree. it should be closed. I'm not fighting over that. Once it's closed, should a false record be kept? Or should it communicate what *really* took place?

Comment: Well, i *do* think a record should be kept; that's why i voted for Olafur's suggestion...

Comment: Who took away their downvote? It was so close on rounding out to 2199. All ruined.

Comment: -1+1 I disliked your initial suggestion, but liked your last edit, so removed my objection. I could always go down-vote a couple other answers if you really want that number...

Comment: Oh, there's plenty to choose from. If you could, it'd help with an OCD number related high. Lasts a few seconds and then it's out.

Comment: (-4) 'cause i'm just an obliging fella.

Comment: Of a glorious fleeting moment of numerical realignment, 2199!

Comment: What's so great about 2199

Comment: Morpheus said something about it.

Comment: I would vote for not showing the name, **but still only allowing a specific close reason to cause a close if enough votes for it are present**. So in the above, you have 3 reasons for "not ninja turtle related", and it would still need 2 votes. On the other hand, the other two people voting for something else contributed their votes to the other close reason(s). That way, you cannot avoid responsibility, because your vote won't be counted.

Comment: @IanElliott [Space Battleship Yamato 2199](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato_2199)

Answer (score 13):

As a close voter, I am uncomfortable with indiscriminate attribution of close reasons shown to readers.

I would much appreciate to have current question closure notice **rephrased to something that doesn't [put words in voter's mouth](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/209295/revisions)**, for example like

> Post Closed by *MichaelT, Eric King, Yusubov, Jimmy Hoffa, gnat*,
>
> with "primarily opinion-based" reason given by <whoever *really* picked that reason, [no *gnat* here please](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6140/31260)>

---

Above is inspired by the approach I sometimes see implemented in off-topic closures [like eg this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/209339/31260):

> put on hold as off-topic by *psr, MichaelT, FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, Eric King, MainMa*
>
> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "Questions about what language, technology, or project one should take up next are off topic on Programmers, as they can only attract subjective opinions for answers. There are too many individual factors behind the question to create answers that will have lasting value. You may be able to get help in The Whiteboard, our chat room." – *psr, MichaelT, Eric King, MainMa*

In above example, *FrustratedWithFormsDesigner* is lucky that notice doesn't stuff into his mouth words he neither wrote nor voted for.

---

There is a whole bunch of feature requests suggesting various ways to resolve improper attribution of close reasons, <sup>but it looks like SE team doesn't give a shit</sup>

- [Could the close vote banner please be made less... well, wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172654/165773)
- [Make it explicit that the majority (and not all) of 5 users closed a question for the mentioned reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114600/165773)
- [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/165773)
- [When you hover over the name of the person closing a question it should show the reason they've chosen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/165773)
- [Show all voted close types when a question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/926/165773)

Comment: Worth noting: the question you are answering is four years old.  It got bumped because somebody decided to add a tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey worth noting: [issue that bumped me](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/6140/revisions "see rev 4 here") into this question, occurred two days ago. Side note my 10th [Necromancer barge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=165773 "listed here") has been awarded at the five years old question (with a nod to [someone having 8 Necromancers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=102937 "guess who's that"))

Answer (score 4):

I had a thought on this matter the other day. When the SCOTUS issues decisions, there is an official decision authored by one member of the majority. Other members of the majority can join that decision, or write a "concurring" opinion.

One could image a message like:

> Closed as "subjective and argumentative" by Joe. Q Random, John Doe, and John Galt with concurring opinions by A. H. Acker, and A. Non Umous.

Probably too confusing, but there it is.

Comment: No, no, no, flagged the question in question as belongs on Usenet, not S&A. Plus, isn't a "concurring opinion" the same?

Comment: When discussing court decisions, a concurring opinion is one which agrees on the result (i.e. which side wins), but differs on the reasoning. Which seems to be exactly what we have in cases like this.

Answer (score 4):

Completely agree, this has always bothered me. I'd say just separate them out:

> **put on hold** as
>
> - *primarily opinion-based* by user1, user2, user4
> - *too broad* by user3, user5

I don't see it reducing comprehension (to the extent people read it at all), and may well give some useful additional feedback to the OP (to the extent people read it at all).

Sometimes, the majority close reason was so silly that I've actually felt the need to add a comment disassociating myself from it (having voted to close for a different reason).

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073856/override-a-method-in-an-object-subclass) is unclear (to me), it could be about subclassing a method (that's what it says it's about), or it could be about having a map with case-insensitive keys. I voted to close as unclear. Then someone else with sufficient rep voted to close as a duplicate of a map-with-case-insensitive keys question, and it says

> marked as duplicate by T.J. Crowder, Duncan

**This is just plain wrong** and I would appreciate it if SO would stop saying I did something I didn't do. As [Jonathan Sampson said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16674/closed-by-is-incorrect#comment33267_16674), suppose we applied this reasoning to elections? I voted, so I must have voted for the winner. Um?!?!