# Questions are being closed without unanimous votes

Tags: support, vote-to-close

This question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491706/smallest-footprint-for-web-application-server

Got closed and migrated to SF after I cast the 5th close vote. But counting mine, there were only 3 votes to migrate it to SF. There was one vote to migrate to SU, and another for Off-Topic I think.

I think I saw *somewhere* that you need 5 votes under the same category to successfully close a question. Or is that just not the case?

Comment: I was shocked that this wasn't already in the FAQ; I've added it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just not the case.  You need 5 votes to close, but they don't all have to be for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

That is just not the case.  Five total votes, plurality rules.  In case of ties, the earliest reason wins.  (Thanks @commenters.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure plurality does rule.

Comment: In the event of a tie between majorities, the earlier close reason wins.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, it only requires 5 *total* votes to close a question.

[Distinguish Close Votes By Reason:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-votes-to-close-by-reason/54997#54997)

> All that matters is that [a user wants] the question to be closed. The specific reason is simply a way of providing feedback to the [OP].

Migration are tools that are meant to ease the users into posting on the correct site, but it secondary to the primary reason of *keeping the original site clean*. So, it does not matter if 5 users disagree about *why* a question is inappropriate, they have still reached the threshold of users indicated that this question **is**, at the very least, inappropriate.