# Close vote isn't done correctly

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions are being closed without unanimous votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61194/questions-are-being-closed-without-unanimous-votes)

Recently I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705901/future-of-an-android-developer?noredirect=1) and I voted to close it. Four already vote the question as off-topic and migrate it to programmers.stackexchange.com. I voted as subjective and argumentive. Now with my vote there were 5 votes and the question was migrated to programmers.stackexchange.com with my account listed as a voter. Is this really the intended behavior?

Comment: Even more: if 4 vote for reason X, and a moderator votes for reason Y (not really a vote, for a moderator), then Y is shown as the reason for all voters.

Comment: @Arjan: this is actually *really useful*, since if four people vote to migrate a question that *shouldn't be migrated*, the moderator must be able to override it (there's no way to "clear" close votes other than closing and re-opening... They do expire eventually, but in cases where a moderator is asked to intervene to prevent an inappropriate migration, this isn't sufficient).