# What reason would appear on closed question with 2 - 2 - 1 votes?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons

What would happen/How would close votes appear in case of

- 1 too localised vote
- 2 not a real question votes
- 2 not constructive votes

How would message about closing look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a "closed" question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

Comment: Does anyone know if there has been discussion to change this?

Comment: @Skooba, discussion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/282094

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The question would be closed with which ever out of "Not a Real Question" or "Not Constructive" was cast last.

The rules are (as far as I know):

1. Take the reason a moderator used to close.
2. Take the reason with >= 3 votes (>= 4 for a migration)
3. In the event of a tie take the reason of the last vote cast out of those involved in the tie.

Answer (score 15):

Jarrod [provided some clarification](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/727/what-determines-the-close-reason-in-the-event-of-conflicts-here/2459#2459) for this on Gaming's Meta (credit to [Grace Note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note) for linking the question in chat), explaining:

> In the event of a tie, the **last** close vote will be used, e.g. in the
>   following order
>
> 1. NaRQ
> 2. off-topic
> 3. NaRQ
> 4. off-topic
> 5. S&A
>
> the question would be closed as off-topic.

This is also reflected in [the FAQ entry on closed posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583), under the section "What if multiple close reasons are used on a question?"