# which close reason appears when a question is closed?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What reason would appear on closed question with 2 - 2 - 1 votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100362/what-reason-would-appear-on-closed-question-with-2-2-1-votes)

If there were 2 votes as "Not Constructive", 2 votes for "Off Topic', and one vote for "Not a real question", which one will appear?

Generally, which reason of the voted reasons will appear when the 5 vote count is reached, and more than one reason is chosen? Is it the most voted or there is a kind of priorities for that?

Comment: As far as I know it takes the last vote cast (for the highest voted reasons) as the result.

Comment: None, in the rare case that a question has attracted all three close reasons, the special "confusing crap" close reason is displayed.

Comment: @Yannis, your comment should be tagged `[feature-request]`.

Comment: Also, if the same happens to migration votes (e.g. 2 voted for offtopic->Site1, 2 votes for offtopic->Site2, and 1 other vote), the question will be just closed, but not migrated anywhere.