# How are closed questions displayed when the reasons are tied?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I'm curious, because I've never seen this scenario happen before. Suppose a question gets close votes. But, two votes are one one reason (like localized), another two votes are on another reason (like not a real question), and the last one is on another (like not constructive). How does StackOverflow handle such scenarios? Does it display both reasons which are tied? Does it display the last one?

Comment: The most recent vote wins.http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100362