# Question Score incorrect on StackExchange profile page

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile, top-questions

On my Stack Exchange [profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1593181/dennis-meng), my second best question by score is currently shown as being +14

[image]

However, its score is currently +15 as you can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207177/what-is-the-correct-way-to-vote-to-close-questions-that-do-not-require-code-but)), and is shown as +15 everywhere else (on Meta profile page, and when I check the Android app).

Why would it be incorrect on my Stack Exchange profile (and only my Stack Exchange profile)?

Comment: Caching? You know not all updates are instant right?

Comment: I have the same issue, with an old question that didn't receive up votes recently and network profile shows +1 votes than the correct value

Comment: @ChrisF The last time either of those questions were upvoted was late January though. Would caching cause it to be wrong for almost 5 months?

Comment: Didn't realise they were old questions. Could be that a user was deleted which would remove their votes.

Comment: @ChrisF my question never arrived to 8 votes

Comment: @ChrisF That would account for at most one of the two though. I don't have any "user was removed" entries in my reputation history since early November (before one of these questions was posted)

Comment: The first one of the two questions got an upvote and now shows the correct score; I've just updated the question. If the second question also corrects itself after another vote (up or down), I'll VTC this as "can no longer be reproduced"

Comment: And of course, as soon as I say that, it gets an upvote and corrects itself. Voting to close this as "can no longer be reproduced"

Comment: I upvoted the question, but the list still wasn't updated in realtime. See if it will have the correct score after 6-8 minutes... **Edit:** It's updated, as always, it's caching.

Answer (score 0):

That post is currently listed on [your profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/1593181/dennis-meng) as having a score of 16, which it currently does.

> [image]

You should [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). (*“caching, it's [always caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/266359)!”*)

Comment: Ordinarily I'd agree, but the score was wrong for about a year, and I cleared my cache several times in that span. Besides, I already said that the scores corrected themselves as soon as both questions went to +16. (Granted, I only said so in the comments. Not sure if people want me to go ahead and put a note directly in the question saying that we're now squarely in "can not be reproduced" land)

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen that comment. Sorry. Usually questions like those are closed, so that people can't answer, but I don't have CV privs (yet?)

Comment: Yeah, it was just taking a while to get the necessary close votes; there were two when you posted the answer. Guess I really should have made it more clear though; comments get overlooked all the time.

Comment: If I had 3K, I would be able to see close votes. What I've done in the past, when whatever bug I had fixed itself, was [post an answer saying the problem went away](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240325/266359), instead of editing the question. I don't know what the right thing to do is, though.