# My flair isn't working!

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair

I put my Flair in the about box on [my profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/266359/shokhet) for Meta.SE, and just discovered that it is not working.

I went back to my profile page on stackexchange.com and copied the Flair HTML code from the [Flair tab there](https://stackexchange.com/users/4326425/shokhet?tab=flair) and pasted it to my about box here (there was no difference between the old and the new HTML code) and that did not solve the problem.

Can we fix this?

[image: screenshot of missing Flair]

**Edit:** Thanks to [Frank](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240323/my-flair-isnt-working?noredirect=1#comment787328_240323), I have discovered (1) it's not just my Flair, it's everyone's (2) it's only combined Flair, not local [for anyone] (3) I'm apparently the only one who has vision problems.

[image: only local, not global]

Comment: It looks ok to me. I can see it.

Comment: @Frank You can see mine or yours?

Comment: @Frank Actually, I can see your Gardening flair, but not your global flair.....

Comment: I can see your flair in your about box.

Comment: [Here's a direct image URL to your flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4326425.png). What happens? Timeout? DNS error?

Comment: @Frank That's odd....the screenshot in my question is exactly what I see (and I refreshed it a bunch of times, including just now)....

Comment: @SantaClaus "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" with a picture of a panda. That appears to have fallen off a slide. It's actually pretty cute, but not what I want to see.....

Comment: @Shokhet Ooh. Never seen the panda before.

Comment: @SantaClaus Your link just worked! Now I see my Flair there.....and everywhere....

Comment: @Oded any special reason why changing to support case instead of a no-repro bug?

Comment: This was last active a month ago, and got a DV today. What gives?

Comment: It's back and mine is damaged, too. Might post another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem went away! I don't know what caused it or why it went away, but now I can see everyone's combined Flair, including mine.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Maybe we caught my Flair in the middle of updating?

Comment: By the way I ran into [the same problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239938/autobiographer-badge-now-only-requires-sharing-what-you-want-with-the-communit/239944#comment786136_239944) some time ago.