# Revisit the formatting of the code based off topic close reasons

Tags: support, review, close-reasons, off-topic, close-dialog

I keep seeing the two code based off topic reasons used incorrectly. I think it is because people focus on the wrong part of the definition for the reason. This is mostly facilitated by the bold text emphasizing, in my opinion, the wrong part of the close reason.

For the sake of reference, this will be #1:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

And #2:

> Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

I believe that this emphasis translates loosely to users in the form of "no specific problem or valid code?" close with #1; "lacks a minimal understanding of what is going on?" close with #2.

However, I do not think this was the intention of these close reasons. I think that the most important part of the text is being overlooked due to the bold emphasis. This is similar to a basic principle in communication.

I didn't say he stole your wallet.
I didn't say he stole *your* wallet.
I didn't say he *stole* your wallet.

3 sentences with the same wording, but all with different meanings. The meanings in these close reasons are being lost. When the discussion to implement these were taking place, it seemed that the point would be to include close reasons for questions which either had code with no problem identified, or questions which just blatantly asked for code.

#1 states the topicality of questions eligible for closure as "Questions concerning problems with code you've written". If there is no code present, this close reason should not be used. But with **describe the specific problem** bolded, some users are confused, some people use it when something trivial is being asked, and sometimes when there is even no code present nor alluded to.

I believe it should have the emphasis given to the topicality of the closure.

> Questions concerning **problems with code you've written** must describe the *specific* problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

This close vote should be for questions where a user included code, but there was no problem with the code, or for when it is not evident what was wrong because the code is a snippet and/or described and not a demo, or it was literally just a massive code dump, etc. It should not be used when there was no code in the question because it clearly states that isn't what it is for. I know most users understand this, but I feel that there are still those who do not get it, and will benefit from the emphasis pointing out the topicality.

#2 states the topicality of questions eligible for closure as "Questions asking for code". I think this is an important close reason. But I think that the topicality is lost under the bolded **demonstrate a minimal understanding**. In fact, I would bet when scanning through this post that this is the phrase which would catch your eye. Probably because it is lightly offensive, especially when bold.

This reason should be used for questions where there isn't really any code and the OP is clearly just asking for a solution to what they "want", "need", "must do", or equivalent popular phrase being used. But when there is a question containing code, this reason does not topically match that (provided that the code wasn't a simple call to the method they "need"). However, questions with code where it seems the OP has copy pasted and clearly lacks an understanding of the code, but where there is a reasonable question, seem to get closed often with this "lack of minimal understanding".

I think changing the emphasis would help here as well.

> Questions **asking for code** must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree 100% with your interpretation of the intent of #1. I've used it to vote to close questions that are of the "My code doesn't work. It's trying to do this thing, but I can't make it work. How do I fix it?" with no code being provided; IMO that fits the description of "problems with code you've written must...include valid code to reproduce it". It's typically quite difficult to explain problems with code you can't see that "isn't working".

Comment: @KenWhite "My code doesn't work, how do I fix it" *with no code* would fall under the category of "unclear what you are asking" if no code was provided. If there is no code, then that does not match this close reason. I believe you should not use a code closure for the situation you describe. "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."-Unclear what you are asking. Without code shown, and OP says "my code isn't working" without showing or explaining, that is unclear.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, for the reasons I stated above. If you have a problem with your code, it's "code you have written", and should be included in your question. "My code doesn't work" quite clearly indicates that you have **written code**, and therefore it's a **problem with code you have written**.

Comment: @KenWhite - Note that if they had described the process but it was still unclear or not specific enough to answer, then I state in my answer the code closure can apply "or for when it is not evident what was wrong because the code is a snippet *and/or described*". But if there is no code, and no code or approach is outlined, I am not sure how this would fit. For example, "My code doesn't work. I was trying to migrate a SQL database in c#, but I can't make it work. How do I fix it?" has nothing to do with code even though it described "this thing" and mentioned "my code"

Comment: @Ken - I guess I don't see it like that. Yes, they have have written code. But if it does not indicate what that code is, nor allude to its process, then it really has nothing to do with that code. In that case it is "unclear" and needs more details (such as more code or more description of the process). Under the assumption that some code was written somewhere, technically every question on SO would be concerning a problem with code the OP has written.

Comment: Fair enough. I still disagree, but that happens. :-) If they have written code, and the question is about code that doesn't work, the question should include the code that doesn't work. "I was trying to migrate something to something else, but it doesn't work" is meaningless without showing what "trying to migrate" involves. "I was trying to migrate a Windows app that does this thing to OSX, but this thing doesn't work" isn't a question.

Comment: @KenWhite - I do appreciate your opinion. And that situation is a hard one to place as well I think. If they should include code that doesn't work, but haven't, which close reason does that fit into? Unclear? Problem with code you have written? I mean, I fully agree it should be closed. I can understand how that would fit more into closed as a result of not including valid code to reproduce the problem. So long as there was already a description of the process or allusion of the approach. I agree that if the "trying to migrate" part is left out, then it is not a question.

Comment: I respect your opinion as well. I just think the issue is with the person voting to close, instead of the close reason. To me, it's clear that if the question indicates there is code involved and the code isn't in the question, it should be closed for that reason. I don't see a purpose in redefining it - it seems to be perfectly applicable.

Comment: Related (and good luck): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202868/please-use-correct-off-topic-close-reason

Comment: I've used #1 to close questions in Ken's scenario too. I've also used #1 to close "no repro" questions: Asker - I have this problem, here is my code. Commenter - I wasn't able to repro. Asker commenting - Oh, I rebooted and it all works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with most of your take on #1, but feel that it also includes when a user hasn't included any code.  There are two things he must do if in the category of:

## problems with code you've written

- must describe the specific problem
- and *include valid code* to reproduce it

and in the second case I think that if they show copy-pasted code they don't understand then it would apply

## asking for code

- *must demonstrate a minimal understanding* of the problem being solved.
- Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

I agree that the close reasons need a little more clarifying and cleaning up.  I agree with your bolding on #1, but think the `minimal understanding` is an important part of #2.

p.s. Sure wish I had `too localized`, it's a real pain to have to use the Other option every time I need it.

Comment: Bring back `too localized`