# Inconsistent behavior of the Dupehammer

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, dupehammer

The "[Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/216721)" behavior seems to be inconsistent. I happened to close a question as a duplicate (instantly) with my "Gold Badge Super Powers"(Yay!) but realized that there was [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) who had voted to close the same question prior to me and even had the "Gold Badge" for the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag under which the now closed question is tagged.

Why wasn't the question closed as a duplicate immediately when the other user [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) (having [java](/questions/tagged/java) gold badge) had voted to close it? Why did the [dupehammer](/questions/tagged/dupehammer) came into effect only after I voted to close it as a duplicate? This seems to be a bit inconsistent to me.

JFYI, this is the question, "[How many String objects are created in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24299064/2024761)", I'm talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just [clarified with MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298884/java-code-cannot-find-resource-file-after-build-and-clean-in-netbeans-ide/24298922#comment37551670_24298922) regarding his close vote. As he said he didn't cast close vote as *duplicate*. He voted to close as *off-topic*. So as per [dupehammer rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/187824) he must vote as *duplicate*. So it's not a bug. It's by design.

Comment: But his name was shown in the marked as duplicate list right? Shouldn't his name have been excluded from the list in that case?

Comment: @R.J That's the list of people who voted to close the question _for any reason_, even if the final reason for closure is not the reason they chose.

Comment: @R.J Really? Can you link to an example? My understanding was that it shows all close voters in the list, regardless of reason.

Comment: @R.J - IIRC this only happens when the question is closed as *off-topic*.

Comment: @AndrewC - I don't have an example at hand but I'm pretty sure I've seen that. May be it is for off-topic reasons alone, but I've for sure seen that.

Comment: @hims056 - Yeah I guess so but the close vote reason and voters list, regardless of the type should be consistent right?

Comment: @R.J - [That is not implemented yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/187824).

Comment: @hims056 - May be I saw something else then. Nevertheless, I guess this answer clarifies my doubt. :)