# Please anonymize rather than incorrectly attribute close reasons to users

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

When a question is closed and the reason is not unanimous (or if a mod steps in), the close text will list the names of those involved in the closure along with the ultimate close reason calculated by the system, for example here in the history of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24473177/revisions):

[image]

This can result in the OP and others assuming *particular* votes were cast, eg in the example above, the OP assumed Craig Ringer had cast an "off-topic" vote, but in reality [he voted to migrate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69438/psql-fatal-sorry-too-many-clients-already#comment125379_69438):

> @JohnMerlino I just voted it for migration. It's seriously annoying the way **Stack Overflow puts my name by it when it's closed when I didn't suggest that**.... oh, it was closed by bluefeet (moderator). I've asked for migration + reopen. Sorry for the confusion...
>   (my emphasis)

Wouldn't it be better to anonymize the users who voted to close with a *different* reason than the eventually accepted one? eg:

> **Post Closed** as "off-topic" by one user and bluefeet♦

or alternatively just:

> **Post Closed** as "off-topic" by bluefeet♦.

In the latter case, if there is not a mod closure, experienced users would know that if there are less than five users shown it means a split decision. The post history could contain a fuller record of the vote.

Comment: There's no "vote to migrate". Migrations start with an off topic vote, the user shouldn't have voted at all if he didn't believe the question was off topic.

Comment: @Yannis I guess that is true in this particular case but it applies in general

Comment: @devnull thanks! I looked but didn't find that for some reason

Comment: This is a duplicate. Please vote to close you post... please. Just for the irony.

Comment: @yannis, I have pointed to the same problem at https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2257/question-on-hold-for-a-different-reason-to-the-reason-i-gave  I also am suprised this question was closed as a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason   I am not against my name being attributed to a majority close reason when I voted for it, but I didn't vote to close for "unclear question". I voted for migration through "Off-topic (Other)"

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd the other post doesn't suggest anonymizing, just a break-down — I was aware of it when I posted this.