# Make the "put on hold" message accurate

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I recently voted to close a question as "too broad;" several others chose "primarily opinion-based." When the question was put on hold, the message shown was:

> **put on hold** as primarily opinion-based by user1, user2, T.J. Crowder, user3, user4

This has always bothered me: Could we please make that message accurate?

> **put on hold** as
>
> - *primarily opinion-based* by user1, user2, user4
> - *too broad* by T.J. Crowder, user3

I don't see it reducing comprehension (to the extent people read it at all), and may well give some useful additional feedback to the OP (to the extent people read it at all).

This particular example is a "meh" (e.g., the question was probably both), but I've sometimes felt the need to actually add a comment disassociating myself from a close reason that made no sense (but was the one the majority picked).

Comment: Didn't it use to be as shown the second example, at least on SO?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, only the off-topic reasons get separated out like that. And if a user hadn't voted as off-topic, their name still gets grouped together into the off-topic main reason, and then just not listed for any sub-reason.

Comment: Also duplicate: [Distinguish close votes by reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason)

Comment: @animuson: *Thank you*, it was really bothering me that I could have sworn I'd seen something like this (listing people separately) before. Must have been off-topics.