# Incorrect user is shown at closed question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, vote-to-close, closed-questions

There was a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34569648/2675154) asked earlier today, so I thought of closing the question, but in the close popup already two other users voted to close as unclear.

Still I went ahead and closed it as duplicate question. Now it is showing:

> marked as duplicate by davidism, Shadow, VR46

But I am the only one who closed it as duplicate. Is this the way it works or is something wrong here?

Comment: Yes, this is how it works. I swear this question has been asked before but I can't find it...

Comment: Shouldn't this be changed

Comment: Dupe of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/310369

Comment: Possibly. I think it isn't a big deal, but it can get a little confusing sometimes (especially when one of the users has a gold tag badge).

Comment: No need to break down and show... atleast dont show the users who didn't vote to close as duplicate when they vote to close as off-topic