# Wrongly states that I marked a question as a duplicate

Tags: bug

This page states that I marked the question as a duplicate, but I never did:

[Python try -except in raw_input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079779/python-try-except-in-raw-input/41079985)

Unlike [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason), I don't think all the different reasons should be listed. I just don't want the statement to be false.

Comment: @Alexander I agree with you: it is misleading. Wording on the lines of "Closed by A, B, C, D, E: marked as duplicate" would be more approprate.

Comment: It's not a bug—It's working exactly as it's intended to. The fact that you disagree doesn't make it a bug (I actually agree with you but that's besides the point).

Answer (score 5):

The close reason displayed is the one chosen by the **majority** of voters. So even if you chose a different reason then it would still display "closed as a duplicate".

The only exceptions to this are when someone uses the gold badge duplicate hammer on a question or a moderator votes to close. Then that overrides all the other close votes regardless of how many there are.

There is a difference when more than one duplicate question is suggested. In this case it displays all of the possible duplicates in the header.

Comment: I'm fine with the question being "closed as a duplicate". What I don't think is okay is that the page lies and says that I voted for the question to be closed as a duplicate, when I did not. I wish to bring across the point to the author of the question that the question is a bad one, for completely different reasons. Also, closing bugs as duplicate says something about a person. For this case, the statement is both public and also incorrect.

Comment: "chosen by the majority of voters" - not true in case of duplicate. If four users vote to close a question as off topic (not as duplicate), and then one user with gold tag hammer close as duplicate, they're all listed in the same way. Happened to me few times here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - forgot about that.

Comment: "The only exception" ...mod vote overrides any previous votes too

Answer (score 2):

You voted to close it for some reason, and when a question is closed, all of the people that voted to close it are listed, and the reason for closure is provided.  it doesn't list out each user's close reason separately.

Comment: The *majority* close reason?

Comment: Yes, the *majority* close reason, which I think is completely misleading.

Comment: @Cai Technically the reason selected may not be a majority.  For example, 2 people could vote to close as  a duplicate and 3 people could each choose a separate close reason.  It seemed extraneous to the question asked here to go over the entirety of the rules for determining which close reason is selected based on the votes given.

Comment: It's always the reason *with the most votes* though right? Come to think of it.... What happens if everyone votes for a different reason?

Comment: @Cai: If I recall, it chooses the first close reason in that case. There's a duplicate question around here somewhere.

Comment: @Aʟᴇ It chooses the reason with the most recent vote, in the event of a tie.