# What determines the "reason" for leaving closed in review that's shown in the close notice?

Tags: support, review, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Today, when reviewing to leave a question closed in the reopen queue, there's an option to select which close reason still applies to the question, or that the original close reason was not resolved. The consensus from the options chosen by the reviewers is shown in the close notice on the question as the overall "reason" why the post was left closed, and it only shows one reason, even if the three reviewers voted for different reasons.

How is this consensus reason selected? I can come up with two conjectures:

- If a moderator reviews the question, the reason they select is the one shown in the notice, even if two other reviewers picked a different (same) reason.
- If at least two users (out of three, no mods) pick the same reason, that will be shown in the notice.

Are those correct?

What about the case where the three users all pick different reasons? Will it fall back to the way close reasons are selected when initially closing the question, that is, the first reviewer's choice will be selected?

Comment: It's a long standing related problem for close votes too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/282094    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325155/282094 both should be fixed with a more detailed banner, or at least [in the timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason#comment923868_54917) ([not fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide)).