# Close votes not showing up on the closure banner

Tags: support, vote-to-close

There was a [question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/23133/a-project-of-mine-on-which-i-could-use-help-two-theorems-on-consciousness-expan) I remember voting to close, but my vote doesn't show up on the closure banner:

[image: Question, closed by one moderator (not OP) as unclear what you're asking]

My vote was cast about two hours before the mod closed/voted it.

[image: Close vote listed in the close vote list in a users profile activity page]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [revision history of the question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/posts/23133/revisions), you'll notice that the question has been closed by you and a moderator:

[image]

but later on it has been reopened and reclosed:

[image]

and since you didn't take part in the *last* closure, you're not attributed in the banner.

Incidentally, if the ♦ moderator disagreed with you that the question is primarily opinion based and wanted to make sure it didn't show in the banner, they could have just voted to close as "unclear what you're asking" since [the reason a ♦ moderator chooses unilaterally determines what ends up on the banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288101/295232).

Comment: The reason for this was probably to change the close reason from "primarily opinion-based" to "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: Yes, that's very likely, but they could've done that in a single step :)

Comment: Maybe they mis-clicked it the first time, maybe because there was a blue badged "1" on the POB choice. Or they changed their mind, right after closing the post. (that was what I originally meant with my comment)

Comment: All possible, we'll never know unless they tell us ..

Comment: @MEE I just made a mistake while closing and selected the wrong reason (which I realized while trying to write a helpful comment). As an unfortunate side effect it ended up looking as it did. I was afraid "primarily opinion-based" would send the wrong message to the OP, so preferred to reopen/reclose. My bad guys. :)