# Make it explicit that the majority (and not all) of 5 users closed a question for the mentioned reason

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distinguish votes to close by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-votes-to-close-by-reason)

It has been requested several times to list all reasons along with the user names who voted to close the question for those reasons, for example here: [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/174063) (and in other posts linked in that question and comments).

The current state in not satisfying because the statement in the text box in a closed question is simply wrong, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8301054/270591 I voted to close the question as a duplicate and not as not a real question. The message says I voted to close as not a real question which is not true.

I would also like one of the solutions mentioned in the other question above but if that doesn't get enough acceptance here are alternative proposals:

- Change the message from **closed as not a real question by...** to **closed as not a real question by the majority of...** or similar.
- Don't mention the users at all who voted to close for other reasons than the majority or say: **closed as not a real question by Jim, Hannah, Bob and two other users.** (The "two other users" refer to "closed", not to "as not a real question".)
- Change the message to: **closed as not a real question by Jim, Hannah, Bob. Jane and Bill voted to close for other reasons.**
- Change the message to: **closed as not a real question and for more reasons by Jim, Hannah, Bob, Jane, Bill ...**

The arguments I saw mainly in the other posts against listing all reasons and users in detail said that such a change would invite discussion and arguing about closing the question. I'd say it doesn't. If a question gets closed for two different reasons it is twice as bad as a question which gets closed for only one reason. It basically means that the question has been closed because it is duplicate **and** not a real question (and not **or**). (Sidenote: The duplicate in the link above got downvotes to -4 while the original (which hasn't been closed as not a real question) has +5 upvotes, but that's another subject.) So, there is even less to discuss about the fact that the question has been closed.

Comment: You think this is really necessary? Community actions are driven by consensus... The given close reason is the *consensus* reason (and the official close reason) because it got the most community votes. I'm not sure we need to always explain minute details like this just because we can.

Comment: See also [Show all voted close types when a question is closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/show-all-voted-close-types-when-a-question-is-closed) and [When you hover over the name of the person closing a question it should show the reason they've chosen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/when-you-hover-over-the-name-of-the-person-closing-a-question-it-should-show-the)

Comment: @Robert: Yes, I think it's necessary or I'd like it at least. If you elect the Democrats but the Republicans win the election would you like to read: "Robert Harvey elected the Republicans" instead of "The majority elected the Republicans"? It's fine to say that *the community* or majority had chosen the following reason to close, but in the message a list of five users is mentioned and not the community.

Comment: That's a little bit of a straw man, but you made me laugh. :P

Comment: @Robert: I was afraid that the example could destroy the seriousness of my request :) Given that this is probably a minor change I'm wondering what is better or the reason to hide this detail. (We are talking about a few words in the text.) I'm pretty sure that if someone reads that X1,X2,X3,X4,X5 closed the question for reason Z he believes that X1,X2,X3,X4,X5 have closed the question for reason Z, and not that the community did it or that a majority is behind that - unless he knows that already. I didn't until the linked question, and that was after more than 1 year activity on SO.