# Could the close vote banner please be made less... well, wrong?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, attribution

Take [this example of a poor question and the outcome of its poverty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15520265/560648):

> closed as not constructive by sgar91, ppeterka, Lightness Races in Orbit, R. Martinho Fernandes, kbok 38 secs ago

Well, okay, fine. I *did* vote to close the question, but as **off-topic**. Because more people voted **not constructive**, that's the aggregate close reason.

However, this banner is essentially saying something that is not true: that *I* think the question is not constructive.

Could the text be re-formed so that it does not lie about my actions and intentions?

Comment: **Almost the same**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-votes-to-close-by-reason

Comment: Almost the same? Not an exact duplicate?

Comment: @Bart: Maybe. The rationale is slightly different. It could be a duplicate, but I'm embarassed that I didn't spot it before. So. :)

Comment: Haha, well, I'd say it's an exact dupe. Perhaps a bounty might be worth it?