# Close off topic issue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, off-topic, attribution

I recently marked a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20283098/821057) off topic, but after 5 votes it start showing my name as closed as duplicated. Which I do not.

> [image]

It should not count or at least state `marked as duplicate by someone` who has not actually did it.

Comment: By design. There's doubtless a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: `votes in off-topic < votes in duplicates`

Comment: @michaelb958 By design yes, by bad design

Comment: @Oded it should only state names of voters who has marked it duplicate.

Comment: This is stack overflow lying by design. Which isn't ideal

Comment: [status: broken-by-design]

Comment: @Oded Why don't you display it the same way as for different off-topic reasons?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - that's how it's been coded. May change in the future, if it comes up as a feature request.

Comment: @Oded both of the [possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172654/could-the-close-vote-banner-please-be-made-less-well-wrong) [duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-votes-to-close-by-reason) are feature requests.

Answer (score 5):

With close voting (except for migration), the main close reason is simply majority rules.

If 3 users vote to close a "primarily opinion based" and 2 users vote to close as "Too Broad", it will be closed and marked as "Primarily Opinion Based", and attributing that reason to all 5 voters.

When you have 3 or more reasons and you no longer have a simple majority is when things get confusing.  At that point, it depends on which majority vote was earliest:

- 2 users vote for Primarily Opinion Based
- 2 users vote for Off-Topic
- 1 user votes for Duplicate

In order to break the tie between primarily opinion based and Off-Topic, the system will choose the close reason of the earliest close vote.

This has been how the system works for as long as I can remember, but the recent Close changes (in June) did take it a step further with the off-topic close reason.

Since "Off-Topic" has multiple sub reasons, when "Off-Topic" is the selected close reason, it will attribute the users who selected each of the sub-reasons separately.

With migration, I believe you need 4 votes to migrate to the same site, so it isn't majority rules anymore but migration is a special case.  If you don't get enough migration votes, it just goes in as Off-Topic.

Given all of this I haven;t really seen a justification of why it is the way it is and if it would be difficult too change.  Personally, I think it should show all of the close reasons, less so for attribution purposes and moreso to convey to the original poster all of the issues with the post.

Comment: yes!!! but mentioning my name in something which I didnt is not correct. If 3 users close it as duplicate show 3 of them.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed I'm just explaining how it works, not why.  I'll expand my answer a bit more though