# Moderator diamond is too large relative to text in meta close reason

Tags: bug, design, meta

Previously I've only ever [seen this in the context of Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176715/155739), but now my Win7 64-bit Chrome 32 is exhibiting the following:

[image: Screenshot]

([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172654/155739))

Comment: looks the same for me also (chrome 32), no repo (IE11), no repo (IE10), no repo (Firefox 26) - looks to be chrome specific

Comment: I _think_ it's Meta-specific too, since Casper's diamond on http://stackoverflow.com/q/1711631/560648 looks normal to me.

Comment: I'm seeing the same large diamond on that link in Chrome

Comment: Interestingly, no repo Chrome 32 on 32-bit Win XP SP3!

Comment: No repro on Firefox 27.0.1 on Windows 7 x64.