# Don't say I marked something as a duplicate when I didn't

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

If I vote to close a question for some reason (perhaps "unclear"), and then the question is marked as a duplicate, it says

> marked as duplicate by T.J. Crowder, Someone, SomeoneElse, AnotherPerson, AFifthPerson

or

> marked as duplicate by T.J. Crowder, SomeGoldBadgeHolder [tag]

This is flat-out wrong. I did not "mark" the question as a duplicate.

Could we please only include the usernames of the people who actually did so when saying who marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @nicael: Possibly (and I've wanted that for a long time too), but this is to my mind a more emphatic use case: It's blatantly saying I did something I simply did not do, whereas "Closed by .... as ..." is at least *partially* correct in that I did participate in closing the question, even if not for the majority reason. (But again, I too really want it split out in that case also.) It's particularly bad in the second form (where I ran into it just now), the dupehammer case (only on SO, I think, at least for now).

Comment: @nicael: This is not a duplicate of that question. That questoni is a [tag:feature-request]. I'm reporting a [tag:bug]. The system still lies about how I voted. This is a problem for people: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172654/could-the-close-vote-banner-please-be-made-less-well-wrong), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261530/i-gave-a-different-close-reason-yet-the-system-lists-me), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181870/), ... **@ Stack Exchange: Why not fix this blatant error?!**

Comment: I wonder how many of the above voted duplicate, since a mod vote always wins the reason?