# Closing Vote with different indication of the chosen reason

Tags: support, voting, vote-to-close

Why when a question is closed, the closing message says that I voted for a different reason than I actually chose, only because it was the most voted by the majority, rather than just tell the user which members voted for closure, and inform the reason of most votes, without indicating that all voted the same option, even when it does not occur?

I asked [this question](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5158/voto-de-fechamento-com-indica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-diferente-do-voto-escolhido) in [Meta StackOverflow in Portuguese](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/), but still got no answer.

Comment: It has been reported before, but I can't find it. This is by design.

Comment: There's no really a "why" here, that's simply the most simple way and changing it requires development time and efforts.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In duplicate there is an answer to this question(I didn't find). There seems to be more suggestions for the message to be changed.

Comment: It was hard to find, all good. But I don't really understand what you mean in the second part of your comment?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry my bad English, is a similar suggestion to the last blockquote of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16748/310559).

Comment: Yep, that's part of being a duplicate, that it got answer on the other question. Cheers! :-)