# What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, attribution

I'm curious, what if a question has 4 votes, 2 for one reason, 2 for other, and the fifth person chooses a third... what is the official *close reason*?

Comment: Probably the first one selected

Comment: It went with "No longer relevant", like Chris, I'd assume that was the first reason added.

Comment: @Timothy, what did you vote? Post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: "No longer relevant" was the first reason selected.

Comment: It is the first one selected. The same if there are 5 different reasons selected.

Comment: Using the first one seems to violate the principle that order doesn't matter.  It should perform a shuffle and pick one at random to be consistent with the answer behavior.  :-)

Comment: ...of course, if `random` was one of the people voting to close, he'd obviously have an advantage with this method.

Comment: On a serious note -- I submitted a feature request to show the close reason for each user at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/when-you-hover-over-the-name-of-the-person-closing-a-question-it-should-show-the.

Comment: Should this be converted into an FAQ? (Should another be posted instead?)  Would mean retagging, editing, and wikifying, but the content would remain largely the same.

Comment: Lets try it on this question, shall we?

Comment: How can this be a duplicate of a question asked 2 years later? It should be the other way around

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With two selections each for `No longer relevant` and `Too Localized`, I selected `Not Stack Overflow related`. It now shows `no longer relevant` as the close reason.

Where there are two selections, the [last vote cast breaks the tie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39658/priority-of-close-votes/39664#39664).

In the case of five different reasons chosen, the first selected will be the one that triumphs.

Comment: No longer relevant was the first as witness by the first name on the list.

Comment: Thanks for the info random person

Comment: This doesn't rule out random selection.

Comment: Why would random get to pick? What if he didn't vote to close?