# Other People in the Picture?

Tags: discussion

When users' profile pics include spouse or kids (or both), is it to be assumed that they all answer and ask questions on StackOverflow together? Or are they in the frame for moral support, generally speaking?

Comment: Wondered what would happen if there were 5 different close votes.

Comment: @squillman, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32700

Comment: @Juan: close, but there were 5 different votes on this one.  Turns out I won.

Comment: @squillman, if you want, you can add that as an answer to that question

Comment: Always friday in iceland?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When users' profile pics include spouse or kids (or both), is it to be assumed that they all answer and ask questions on StackOverflow together?

Yes.

Comment: As it is safe to assume that Jeff answered this question while falling in a floor trap.

Comment: relevant: http://i47.tinypic.com/2py82l0.jpg

Answer (score 7):

If a custom gravatar is used, the profile picture must always be of the user. If you observe any violations of this rule, please report it to the site management.

Comment: Wait, is this meant ironically? Are you trying to tell us that you are NOT a very smart cat and possibly the only cat ever to gain more than a thousand Rep on Meta? Wow, thanks for shattering my dreams of a world ruled by intelligent cats, no milk for you tonight!

Comment: I used to be an abstract pattern, but now I have emerged through my three-legged frog-like state as a beautiful helicopter.

Answer (score 1):

The profile picture (avatar) doesn't necessarily have to be a picture of the account owner. Very often it's just a picture the owner likes.

Answer (score 1):

If a profile picture is of multiple people then it is assumed the youngest is the one at the keyboard asking questions.