# What happens when everybody votes to close a question for a different reason?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32700/what-happens-if-a-fifth-person-chooses-a-different-reason-to-close)

I'm just curious what happens when all five votes to close a question are different. Which reason is displayed?

Comment: One tidbit that's not on the duplicate, is that diamond close votes always win, so if a question has, for example, four not constructive votes and a moderator votes to close as not a real question, not a real question it is.

Comment: It happened today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348463/duplicated-code-above-and-inside-while-loop

Comment: In a rather hilarious manner: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4401471#4401471