# What if 5 votes to close are of kinds disagreed to each other?

Tags: bug, questions, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32700/what-happens-if-a-fifth-person-chooses-a-different-reason-to-close)

At first I wanted to ask if all 5 votes to close should be of same kind, but I see this was already asked: [Distinguish close votes by reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-votes-to-close-by-reason).

So, I ask different question. I am not sure, but probably I had a case where:

- 2 votes for "not constructive"
- 3 votes for "exact duplicate"

My concern is that: two voters think the Question is "not constructive" - so the older question should also be "not constructive"? If not, the old question is constructive - then this one is not "exact duplicate"?

My personal opinion is that system shall not combine votes from different kinds, especially from such opposite kinds.

Just a real life example to show what I mean: consider 5 judges votes are needed to sent a person to prison after the given road accident. 3 judges votes because he/she was pedestrian causing this accident, 2 votes because he/she was car driver causing the accident. The one man cannot be pedestrian and car driver at the same moment, and the question cannot be "not constructive" and "exact duplicate of constructive question".