# How could the "close question" process be improved?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9968421/378979) we have a perfectly formatted and clear question about things related to programming. There was 10 people voting +1 on the question, many more (20+) who voted for the answers, and still ... it was closed because 5 closed-minded peers decided so.

How could we improve the "close question" process so that minorities won't be able to decide what is good or what is bad for majorities?

**EDIT:** Note that the pointed question is conform with this criteria from the FAQ ... "*practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession*".

Comment: This is an invalid question for a Q&A site about programing. It was closed off-topic because why protocol designers decided on any particular part of their protocol is subjective at best and further has _nothing_ to do with programming.

Comment: The question was not "how" but "why". This is not subjective. Also, this is not the topic of my present question. I am talking here about anti-democratic question closing system.

Comment: typo - fixed now... -- re your edit (or maybe what I didn't read the first time around): You can't fix something that isn't broken. The FAQ clearly defines what is appropriate for SO. If a question varies from it's bounds, expect it to be closed.

Comment: Let's suppose that you are right. I would still like to discuss about ways to improve the question closing process.

Comment: I doubt it will change. People (apparently meaning people _other than you_) are happy with how it works. Changing it would go against what the SE network is about. Ask your questions on-topic, proving enough prior effort, and you'll likely be fine.

Comment: I'd like to **STRESS** that I am asking here a question not specifically bound to my previous question. How about 5 misc users closing a question which is not off-topic? Don't tell me that it never happens.

Comment: @Vincent Then 5 other users vote to reopen it. Closing isn't permanent

Comment: I didn't know about that, probably because the reputation value on my account is not high enough for me to notice it. Out of curiosity, was there cases where the close/open was fluctuating (since a fluctuation would only require 5 angry closers and 5 angry openers)?

Comment: @Vincent [Sure](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1995113/revisions?page=3). You might want to read the privilege page on [close/reopen votes](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: *" 5 closed-minded peers decided so"* **Hah!** I see what you did there!

Comment: Also, care to justify *how* this is "anti-democratic"? The closing system is democratic *by definition*. People get to vote to close. If 5 of them agree (a majority), then they "win". Then people can vote to re-open. If 5 of them agree (a majority), then *they* "win".

Comment: Starting a war is never constructive so closing this question is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Where did you see that 5 out of an undefined number is a majority?

Comment: What is the problem?  You got plenty of answers and even accepted one -- who cares if it's now closed?

Comment: Congratulations, on the top of being closed, now the question is deleted, even when there was 4 votes to reopen it and plenty of people satisfied of the question. And now? Is there a way to undelete it? It makes me want to stop contributing when I see that.

Comment: It's amazing to see people downvoting the question 7 years after it was asked.
The context of SO has changed since, downvoting it now may not really be relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you actually have an idea, the standard "I'm upset my question got closed so I propose we scrap the whole close vote system" post is useless. Your question has nothing to do with programming, it has to do with the history of URIs. It's also in no way a [problem that you need to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), it's just an idle curiosity. I wanted to vote to close as soon as I saw it, but couldn't decide if it would be better migrated somewhere; when I checked in later it already had enough off-topic votes that it didn't matter anymore, so I finished it off

Comment: Yes I am upset .. not because of people who closed the question, because they have the power to do so. The idea that I propose is to not close a question when the closers are a minority + wait at least 10 minutes to close a question.

Comment: @Vincent Your question closed over 6 hours later; where did you come up with a 10 minute grace period? As for your "majority/minority" argument, the same number of people can vote to reopen. You want to make it so upvotes by random drive-by users are the same as preemptive reopen votes, which I think you'd realize is kind of insane if we were discussing a question other than your own

Comment: Those 10 minutes I suggest are not related to my question. It is the time it takes to have a kind of stability in the representation of different categories of SO voters. I noticed that SO also wait 10 minutes before one could accept an answer, probably to let enough time to people to answer for the sack of fairness.

Comment: @Vincent 10 minutes is an awfully long time to force a post to remain on the front page when it might be completely terrible, on the off-chance that 5 users immediately closed a question that was actually good and should've stayed open. Also, it's already been suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120260/time-limit-for-vote-to-close)

Comment: There is still 1 way the closing process could be improved: by giving a reason. Sometimes it is not clear why a question was closed (for instance http://stackoverflow.com/q/6911030/378979) while the system knows what reason each closer chose. How about displaying it next to the names of the closers?

Comment: @Vincent [Good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54919/145982) :)

Comment: Then .. is this feature scheduled for implementation somewhere?

Comment: @Vincent Not yet; there are [quite a few feature requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request). There are red status tags if a feature has been categorized (e.g. [status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined)), but that one doesn't have one, so it hasn't been processed. I imagine it won't happen, since it's fairly unimportant, but at least it hasn't been outright rejected yet

Comment: @Vincent Although [this version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/show-all-voted-close-types-when-a-question-is-closed) was rejected, so not a good sign