# Serial downvoting causes poor appearance in reputation tab

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, serial-voting

In the past 2 days I have been serially downvoted by some user within a minute or so! I have read the following questions in MSE regarding serial downvoting however my questions here are somewhat different.

- [Victim of serial downvoting banned after serial downvoting reversed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179065/victim-of-serial-downvoting-banned-after-serial-downvoting-reversed)
- [Serial downvoting on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127803/serial-downvoting-on-mso)

I have attached a screenshot showing the downvotes that I have received.

[image]

- As you can see in the image yesterday some user has serially downvoted within a span of 5 minutes! But today it was reversed which is fine! [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/286481) informs me all the things regarding what should be done or what the system will do in turn to correct these things.

  My doubt is regarding how this looks in the reputation history, as the serial downvotes look really weird in the reputation tab of my profile. Today, most people give reference to their Stack Overflow profile to recruiters to show what skills they have, but this history in the reputation tab looks odd and might cast a bad light towards me if the recruiter does not know what serial voting is. Is there any way to correct this?
- What if the system does not recognise this serial downvoting and does not correct my reputation?
- Let's say the serial downvoter got banned from the community. What if he creates another account and starts downvoting again? He could create any number of accounts (with new emails I presume) and continue to downvote? How could this be prevented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My doubt is regarding how this looks in the reputation history, as the serial downvotes look really weird in the reputation tab of my profile. Today, most people give reference to their Stack Overflow profile to recruiters to show what skills they have, but this history in the reputation tab looks odd and might cast a bad light towards me if the recruiter does not know what serial voting is. Is there any way to correct this?

Unfortunately, no. But do you really want to work for a company who can't even tell that something like that looks suspicious? Anyway, you'd hope a prospective employer look at **your posts**, not your *rep*!

> What if the system does not recognise this serial downvoting and does not correct my reputation?

It will. The system runs thorough checks daily and getting 8-10 downvotes by the same user (which is almost definitely the case here) in 1 minute is definitely suspicious to say the least. *If* (in the very unlikely event) is it not reversed after 24 hours, use the 'contact us' link (at the bottom of every page) to inform Stack Exchange - they will investigate, reverse the actions, and probably ban the user doing this.

> Let's say the serial downvoter got banned from the community. What if he creates another account and starts downvoting again? He could create any number of accounts (with new emails I presume) and continue to downvote? How could this be prevented?

He won't be able to. You need 125 rep to downvote posts. A person must *really* hate you if he's going to create loads of accounts, get 125 rep on each of them, downvote your posts, get banned, and start again!

Comment: @grgarside - thanks for the suggestion - *I* would have approved it - but looks like the other 2 got there before me and rejected it! Sorry.