# "loading when this answer was accepted..." forever!

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, accepted-answer, tooltips

In the suggested edit queue, hovering over the accepted answer symbol, gives you a tooltip `loading when this answer was accepted...` - but that never goes away (even if I move my cursor off of it and back again) - it's never replaced by the actual time!

[image]

[For example, this suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/39303).

Can it be fixed? Or at least, removed?

Comment: Whilst we're here, why was that edit rejected? The original question was copy edited, so why not update the quoted content in the answer?

Comment: @grgarside I don't know - see [my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257119/serial-downvoting-causes-poor-appearance-in-reputation-tab/257120#comment838749_257120) on that answer :)