# Leave auto-generated comment on closed as off-topic

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

That would be similar to the auto-generated comment after someone votes to close a question as duplicate.

Imagine a question is off-topic and gets closed. The users that closed the question selected an alternative website while closing.

When the question is closed there is no hint that there might be a very similar site where (s)he could ask the question like [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) for example.

How about leaving an auto-generated comment like

> This question would be a better fit for superuser.com.

if the users that closed the question selected a unique alternative website?

Comment: If the question is actually suitable for Super User, why would it have been closed instead of migrated in the first place?

Comment: It's already the case that [if 4 out of 5 of the close-voters agree on a migration target, the post will be migrated there automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97700). So I guess you are asking for [all close-vote reasons to be shown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/926/show-all-voted-close-types-when-a-question-is-closed) ? That has been [meta-tag:status-declined]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the post deserves migration, it will likely be migrated.

If not (usually because it's a poor question, or a duplicate on the other SE site), we don't want to encourage re-posting, or in the event that the question isn't closed at all: cross-posting.

Of course, you are welcome to post the comment manually if you see fit, but I don't see any value in auto-generated comments of this nature.