# Close as duplicate: ability to change target Q&A

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Occasionally when I am the first to cast a "Close as duplicate"-vote, and search for a target Q&A to reference, it happens that I shortly after that stumble over another Q&A that would actually be a better fit. In these cases I really miss the ability to edit my duplicate-vote to reference that other Q&A instead, which is a pity since I think it's common for following voters to perhaps not go and read the Q&A, but just vote for the same one as the first voter.

I saw the feature request [Improve tools for closing as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77103/130074), which would probably decrease (if not completely remove) this "problem", so if that one would be implemented this one would not be of interest anylonger, I think.

Comment: Related, or more generic: [Ability to change close reason before it gets closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/ability-to-change-close-reason-before-it-gets-closed).