# How should I update the link used for marking a question as duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I tried to search but couldn't find an answer to this. The problem seems to be very basic.
I saw a question on SO and found that It's a duplicate of another question so decided to cast Close vote on it. While doing so I selected the reason as duplicate but I accidentally provided a wrong link. Now, when I click again, the dialog opens but there's no way to update the link. How should I do that?

Comment: You can't. You can either retract your vote or offer the correct link in a comment. Alternatively you could post a cv-pls duplicate [question link] is duplicate of [target] is the SOCVR chat room but do read their FAQ before posting: https://socvr.org/faq

Comment: If I retract, I can't close it again. Nor can I flag it. Yeah I just commented.

Comment: Putting the proper link in a comment should be fine. Note that mods & gold tag badge holders can edit the duplicates list. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/334566

Comment: Related feature request: [Close as duplicate: ability to change target Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84237/295232)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A viable course of action without retracting the close vote would be:

1. Delete the automatically generated comment from your close as duplcate vote
2. Rephrase the duplicate proposal comment manually:

   > Does this answer your question? `[link title](link)`

The new proposal will appear in the list shown to other close voters.

For flagging it's the same, but you might consider to retract your flag in order to avoid it appearing in the list of declined flags.

If you're a gold badge holder, and closed the question single handedly, you can edit the duplicate box directly:

1. Add the new duplicate link to the duplicate box
2. Remove the old one