# Flagged as Low Quality - can't flag as Dupe

Tags: discussion, support, flags

I already flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15512347/1563422) as Low Quality, and posted a comment to that effect.

But then the OP asked why it was low quality, so I searched and found an [exact duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9572604/1563422).

When trying to flag as a dupe, I get the *Post already flagged* error.

I don't know whether this is something that can be changed when flagging for a different reason?

Or is there something else I should have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once you've flagged to close for any reason there's no going back.

Here's the [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) to allow you to change that vote (it's currently the number one status-declined feature request on Meta).

Here's one to allow you to [swap close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/ability-to-change-close-reason-before-it-gets-closed).

Comment: Thanks for that Lance; I can see the questions are related, but that feature request is to be able to completely *rescind* a flag. I'm referring to *swapping* flags.

Comment: I was thinking the idea would be to rescind, then revote.  There is no way to swap flags to a different reason.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense... ok, status-declined it is! I'll accept soon.

Comment: @DannyBeckett, here's a link for a [swap feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/ability-to-change-close-reason-before-it-gets-closed).

Comment: Nice! Feel free to close this question as a dupe of that (ironic really).